# Rendering html in react with hooks not working

Tags: reactjs

I have a Task component which shows what task i need to do and when, and i want this to auto update when its time for it to change. So i was trying to do something like this

```js
function Task(){
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [currentTask, setTask] = useState();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/api")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data.tasks));
    }, []);
    function determineTask(){
        Object.keys(data).map(function(key, index){
            if(msSinceDayBegan > data[key].startMs && msSinceDayBegan < data[key].endMs){
                setTask(data[key].task);
                const nextIndex = Object.keys(data)[index+1];
                setTimeout(determineTask, (data[nextIndex].startMs - msSinceDayBegan))
            } 
        })
    }
    if(data && !initialized){
        initialized = true;
        determineTask();
    }
    console.log(currentTask);

  return(
        <div>
            {console.log("inside return")}
            <p>{currentTask? currentTask: "Loading..."}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

when I log `currentTask` I get back the result I want. However, before that, there are a few logs of undefined, but at the end, it prints out the actual value of the task and then logs "inside return". But the only thing getting rendered on my app is "loading...", why is this? currentTask has a value, am I missing something? I've tried all that I could but I couldn't understand it.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look at documentation, usestate, useEffect dependency, asynchronously setstate

Comment: I went through the documentation for useState and useEffect, I'll go through asynchronous setstate now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the function `determineTask()` is being called before the data is fetched. Data fetching often takes a couple seconds, and the `determineTask()` function is being called as soon as the component renders.

I would suggest putting the block of code:

```
function determineTask(){
    Object.keys(data).map(function(key, index){
        if(msSinceDayBegan > data[key].startMs && msSinceDayBegan < data[key].endMs){
            setTask(data[key].task);
            const nextIndex = Object.keys(data)[index+1];
            setTimeout(determineTask, (data[nextIndex].startMs - msSinceDayBegan))
        } 
    })
}
if(data && !initialized){
    initialized = true;
    determineTask();
}
console.log(currentTask);
```

inside a `useEffect`. `useEffect` has a second parameter of a dependency array that will trigger the `useEffect` to run again when one of the dependencies change.

In your first `useEffect`, you're changing the `data` state variable and then you want the `currentTask` state variable to change once you've retrieved the data.

So, your second `useEffect` will look something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function determineTask(){
        Object.keys(data).map(function(key, index){
            if(msSinceDayBegan > data[key].startMs && msSinceDayBegan < data[key].endMs){
                setTask(data[key].task);
                const nextIndex = Object.keys(data)[index+1];
                setTimeout(determineTask, (data[nextIndex].startMs - msSinceDayBegan))
            } 
        })
    }
    if(data && !initialized){
        initialized = true;
        determineTask();
    }
    console.log(currentTask);

},[data]);
```